# Given a sorted list, return as many elements to reach a total

Tags: python

If I have a sorted list of objects that have a value value. Is there a more pythonic way of returning the first elements that add up to a given target?

```
>>> def func(list, target=0):
     current = 0
     for x in list:
       current += x.value_attr
       yield x
       if current >= target:
         return
>>> [x for x in func(list,target=3000)]
```

Comment: Looks good. Don't name your variables after builtins like `list`. Then you can just do `list(func(items, target=3000))` instead of the comprehension.

Comment: can you show an example input and output list?

Comment: @mu無 Without more description of what this code achieves and a lot more context it would be off-topic there.

Comment: I think `break` is more natural and clearer than `return` here

Comment: Maybe `functools.reduce()` with an `itertools.takewhile()`?

Answer (score 0):

Another lazy way is to use `itertools.accumulate` with a generator expression:

```
from itertools import accumulate

lst = [1, 3, 1, 0, -5, 100, 10, 20, -15]

res = next((i for i, j in enumerate(accumulate(lst)) if j >= 20), 0)  # 5
```

If you need all the values which accumulate up to the target, just index using this result:

```
lst_filter = lst[:res+1]

# [1, 3, 1, 0, -5, 100]
```

Comment: The OP’s approach is also lazy, I’m not clear what advantages your approach has? The list slicing part of yours isn’t lazy of course

Comment: The question said more pythonic. As such it is ambiguous. I present one way.